# Create Parallel Task for several Service Call in C# Parallel Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, task

I Want to get the information from various Service. How could I achieve all the service call could be perform in a same time **using C# Task, not by thread**.

**C# Code which I was tried:**

```
 void GetServiceList() {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        var List1 = client1.GetList1();
        var List2 = client2.GetList2();
        var List3 = client3.GetList3();
        var List4 = client4.GetList4();
        var List5 = client5.GetList5();
        var List6 = client6.GetList6();
        var List7 = client7.GetList7();
        var List8 = client8.GetList8();
        var List9 = client9.GetList9();
        var List10 = client10.GetList10();
    });
}
```

In the above code, the task is created but the service call is happened sequentially. I wish to make it as Parallel.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did you try to create the relevant Tasks? Did you encounter a problem? If you don't know how to use Tasks at all, check a tutorial. There are hundreds of tutorials that explain how to start multiple tasks.

Comment: yes. I tried but it call one by one Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {  ... Statements ... }); within this I called all the Services.

Comment: Post what you tried in the question itself. BTW you *can* call `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` multiple times and await all the results. This is a fundamental concept though. You should really read a tutorial first, instead of trying to throw together some code. You may find that there are other ways to invoke many actions at the same time

Comment: I updated the code for your reference. I'm new in Task oriented programming. I reviewed some basic tutorial and I got this structure. If any thing wrong in my code kindly assist me as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is creating an anonymous method that calls each service in turn and then executes that method in a parallel task.  What you need is a task array.

```
List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
Task task1=
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                var List1 = client1.GetList1(););

Task task2=
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                var List2 = client1.GetList2(););

// and so forth

taskList.Add(task1);
taskList.Add(task2);

Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have any control over the Service you are calling I suggest you make the call async so you can await the Task instead of using Task.Factory.StartNew()

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need control over the service, as it's inherently async, and you can take advantage of that. These two will happily communicate with each other, and give you a synchronous server and an asynchronous client:

Server-side definition:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    IResult DoStuff(IParameter parameter);
}
```

Client-side definition:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginProcess(IParameter parameter, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);
    IResult EndProcess(IAsyncResult result);
}
```